# Concurrent entrancy occurs despite of use of SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, semaphore

I expected the following `Connected` and `Disconnected` handlers are called alternately.

But it wasn't. It is not 100% reproducible but sometimes the test failed. Repository is [here](https://github.com/jeiea/ObsStrawket/blob/4f5b9d73274a836de4a9f92e2817759e7e9ad19a/ObsStrawket.Test/ClientStressTest.cs#L46).

I attach simplified code here because full code will be long. Please refer to the repository for the reproducible example.

```cs
  public class ClientStressTest3 {
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestAsync() {
      var client = new Client();
      int openCloseDifference = 0;
      var failures = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

      client.Connected += () => {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref openCloseDifference);
        int difference = openCloseDifference;
        Debug.WriteLine("Connected: {}", difference);
        if (Math.Abs(difference) > 1) {
          // Failure point. Why enter here?
          _ = failures.Writer.WriteAsync($"open close difference {difference}");
        }
      };
      client.Disconnected += () => {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref openCloseDifference);
        int difference = openCloseDifference;
        Debug.WriteLine("Disconnected: {}", difference);
        if (Math.Abs(difference) > 1) {
          _ = failures.Writer.WriteAsync($"open close difference {difference}");
        }
      };

      var tasks = new List<Task>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
          try {
            await client.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
          }
          catch (Exception ex) { }
        }));
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
          try {
            await client.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
          }
          catch (Exception ex) { }
        }));
      }
      await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
      while (await failures.Reader.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) {
        string failure = await failures.Reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        throw new Exception(failure);
      }
    }
  }

  class Client {
    public event Action Connected = delegate { };
    public event Action Disconnected = delegate { };

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _connectSemaphore = new(1);
    private Task _dispatch = Task.CompletedTask;
    private WebSocket _clientSocket;

    public async Task ConnectAsync() {
      await _connectSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      // _dispatch may be same among multiple threads if restored at the same time.
      try {
        await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (_dispatch != null) {
          _dispatch = _dispatch.ContinueWith((_) => DispatchEventAsync(), TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
      }
      finally {
        _connectSemaphore.Release();
      }
    }

    private async Task DispatchEventAsync() {
      try {
        Connected();
      }
      catch (Exception exception) { }
      try {
        while (await events.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) {
          DispatchEvent(await events.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
        }
      }
      catch (Exception exception) { }
      try {
        Disconnected();
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
  }
```

I think `_connectSemaphore` will guard the inner code execution, and only one thread will execute `DispatchEventAsync`.

But it seems sometimes two threads enter `DispatchEventAsync` at the same time. I can't understand this.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do there are *far* better ways to do it than all this hard to read code. For example, instead of locking and multi-way blocking between threads, you could queue requests eg using a Dataflow block or Channel, and have *one* worker task use the client. There shouldn't be any need for locks and semaphores if you use Channel, IAsyncEnumerable, `await foreach`, `Parallel.ForeachAsync`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I'm using Channel in the repository. If you saw improvement point could you elaborate more?

Comment: Explain what you actually want to do. You aren't using channels in the client. You can use a Channel to queue requests to the client. The *client* should provide the Event and Failure channels instead of using events that eventually post to those channels. Or it could provide an `IAsyncEnumerable` stream for each, to completely hide the channels

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm aware use of Channel may be desirable, but I also think it is just one of the methods. Thanks for your comment, but I'm not requesting code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ContinueWith` is a low-level method with dangerous default behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) (link is to my blog). In this case, your code is not behaving how you think it should because `ContinueWith` (like `StartNew`) doesn't understand asynchronous delegates.

Specifically, the task returned from `ContinueWith` (the same task stored in `_dispatch`) will complete when `DispatchEventAsync` asynchronously yields (i.e., hits its first `await` that asynchronously waits). This is likely the call to `WaitToReadAsync`, which is after `Connected` and before `Disconnected`. So the `_dispatch` task completes after `Connected` and before `Disconnected`.

Ideally, you should avoid `ContinueWith` completely. Sometimes a local asynchronous method helps, e.g.:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync() {
  await _connectSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  try {
    await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (_dispatch != null) {
      _dispatch = ChainAsync(_dispatch);
    }
  }
  finally {
    _connectSemaphore.Release();
  }

  static async Task ChainAsync(Task dispatch)
  {
    await dispatch;
    await DispatchEventAsync();
  }
}
```

If you do want to continue using `ContinueWith` for some reason, then you can use `Unwrap`:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync() {
  await _connectSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  try {
    await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (_dispatch != null) {
      _dispatch = _dispatch.ContinueWith(_ => DispatchEventAsync(), TaskScheduler.Default)
          .Unwrap();
    }
  }
  finally {
    _connectSemaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Using either of these approaches, the `_dispatch` task will now complete at the *end* of `DispatchEventAsync`.

Comment: Why I can't upvote this twice.

Answer (score 1):

> I think _connectSemaphore will guard the inner code execution, and only one thread will execute DispatchEventAsync.

Nope.  Because you don't wait or await _dispatch.  The semaphore only protects starting the task.  The execution of the task happens in the background sometime after you release the semaphore.

> But I'm chaining it with ContinueWith. Isn't it sufficien

No.  That just adds another task that runs after; it doesn't actually run the task or wait for it to complete.  If you want to run the _dispatch and then another task while holding the semaphore, just

```
await _dispatch;
await DispatchEventAsync();
```

Comment: But I'm chaining it with `ContinueWith`. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: @jeiea you're misusing channels and tasks. It's better to explain what you actually want to do in the question. It will be easier to show how it can be done than try to make sense of all this. For example, you can have a `Channel` with *requests* and a single task reading from it and using the Client without requiring locks. You could expose that channel's Writer as a property of the client, or the client constructor could accept a `ChannelReader<Request>` or `IAsyncEnumerable<Request>` provided from the outside

Comment: My thought is that `.ContinueWith()` will be `DispatchEventAsync().ContinueWith((_) => DispatchEventAsync()).ContinueWith((_) => DispatchEventAsync()) ...`. 
Of course second `DispatchEventAsync` may not be in semaphore guard. But it won't start before the first `DispatchEventAsync` finishes. And `Connected` and `Disconnected`'s call order is guaranteed in `DispatchEventAsync`, so I thought it has no problem.
Still I'm not convinced by the answer yet.